# Python remove try inside except?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

In python I have a function called `func()` which could raise `NoSuchElementException`:
I'm trying to call it with `input1` if not correct call it with `input2` else give up.

Is there any better way to write this code for clarity:

```
submit_button = None
try:
    submit_button = func(input1)
except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        submit_button = func(input2)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

Comment: what do we know about `input1` and `input2` and how do they look if it fails? (Not defined, `None`, `[]`, etc..). And what happens if both of them fail?

Comment: @Finn as I said  if func() fails it raises NoSuchElementException Exception, input1 and input2 are different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
for i in [input1, input2]:
    try:
        submit_button = func(i)
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(f"Input {i} failed")
else:
    print("None of the options worked")
```

If the first input doesn't throw an exception you break the loop, otherwise you keep in the loop and try the second input.

This way you can try as many inputs as you want, just add them into the list

The else at the end executes if you never broke the loop, which means none of the options worked

This works well if you want to try several inputs and treat them equally. For only two inputs your code looks readable enough to me. (try this, if it doesn't work try that)

Comment: why you have else? no if here...

Comment: for loops also have an else, which executes if the loop terminated normally (no breaks). take a look at https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

Answer (score 0):

Just another option...

```
from contextlib import suppress

submit_button = None
for i in input1, input2:
    with suppress(NoSuchElementException):
        submit_button = func(i)
        break
```